# java float format specifier

Tags: java, java-8, formatting, printf

I want to achieve the following formatting while printing the float.

> Consider following example →

- 5.55555555 → 5.5555
- 9.0 → 9

For the first part I used

```
System.out.printf("%.4f",5.5555556f);
```

When I pass the 9.0 to same snippet above it gives output as `9.0000` . Please help me solve this problem. ✌️

Comment: "5.555555556 → 5.5556" and "9.0 → 9" are two different formats. When do you want it to format to 4 decimal places, and when do you want it to format to the nearest integer?

Comment: you can simply cast the value to integer to truncate the decimal, as you've specified it formats your float upto 4 decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalFormatting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double answer = 5.0;
        double answer1 = 5.55555555;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.####");
        System.out.println(df.format(answer));
        System.out.println(df.format(answer1));
    }
}
```